# mysql - check before creating

Tags: mysql

I am creating tables in mysql 5.7  version, such as but would like to check if table exists before creating. or another scenario have some try catch block , where if table exits and i execute create again, it throws an error . i can catch that and log it.

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CreateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UpdateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UserId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address1` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `State` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `fk_address_user_UserId_idx` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_address_user_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `user` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Add this: 'IF NOT EXISTS'.  Ex: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...

Comment: Exactly. You don't want a prior check, as that introduces a timing-window problem.

Comment: However, if the old table definition is different from the one you want, you won't recreate it and you'll have the wrong table structure.

Comment: This is a strange requirement. You should know what tables exist in your schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can dynamize schema and table names I've written a udf once to be used in a stored procedure like:

```
IF fn_table_exists('my_schema', 'table_to_be_created') THEN
   SELECT 'Table Already exists!';
END IF;
```

---

#### Implementation:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_table_exists(dbName VARCHAR(255), tableName VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS TINYINT(1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE totalTablesCount INT DEFAULT (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM information_schema.TABLES
      WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA COLLATE utf8_general_ci = dbName COLLATE utf8_general_ci)
        AND (TABLE_NAME COLLATE utf8_general_ci = tableName COLLATE utf8_general_ci)
    );
    RETURN IF(
      totalTablesCount > 0,
      TRUE,
      FALSE
    );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```